# Java slowing down my computer

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program that's running some complex video analysis programs which i wrote in Java.

My IDE is Eclipse. After a couple of runs my program is really slow until i close Eclipse and run

```
pkill -f 'java -jar'
```

and

```
pkill -f 'java'
```

I guess this is because of some locked resources. Is there a way I can account for this in my program?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS by the way

Comment: Try running it outside the IDE and define parameters like max permgen size yourself.

Comment: How much memory is in use while running? You could have allocated too much memory and hitting swap which will cause your computer to run like a dog.

You can also limit your JVMs memory : http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: Make sure your program really *terminates* and doesn't leave a lingering VM in the background.

Comment: would defining my own maxpermgen affect the performance of my program?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and found that when I stopped a program, that I started in Eclipse, it wasn't being terminated.  If you look at your console, window within Eclipse, you'll an Icon that looks like a Computer monitor.  Click on the arrow button beside the monitor and see what all is still running.  If you have a bunch of processes listed that don't have  leading the name then they are all still running and need to be stopped.  You can select one and click on the Red square along the toolbar of the console window to stop it.